# Having issues with some homework, C programming stuff

Tags: c

So the problem is to add 3 numbers together(2's complement) in C.  Normally should be very simple, but the hard part of this problem is that you can only use the ops ! ~ & ^ | << >>, no kind of loops, or function calls, or anything fancy.  Just those ops.  He gives us a function that adds 2 words together.  The return of the function I'm writing (sum3) is return sum(word1, word2).  My responsibility is to determine what to set word1 and word2 to in order for the call to the sum function to give me the proper answer.  Oh, and also I can only use 16 total of those ops up there.

I tried setting word1 to x ^ y, and word2 to (x & y) << 1 to see if I at least got the right answer from that for the first 2 numbers, and it always ends up correct.  However, I have no idea how to throw z into the mix without messing everything up.  I think this is is the biggest problem...somebody please help, I messed up and didn't realize this was due in 5 hours from now, so I'm freaking out.  At least a good hint...something, anything.

Comment: Could you give more details? An example maybe? Sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding the question :-)

Comment: No idea where 'z' is coming from, and what sum() and sum3() are (to each other). Or why you need to set up the arguments (word1, word2)

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess in my rush I wasn't explaining things well.  Essentially what I'm given is a function to complete, sum3, which takes 3 parameters, x y and z.  sum3 calculates the sum of x y and z without me using any + ops.  He provides a function call in the return statement of sum3, which is sum(word1, word2) which adds word1 and word2 normally.  Inside sum3, I have to set word1 and word2 equal to whatever I need to be able to add the 3 (x y and z) together.

Comment: Sounds like you interpret the phrase "My responsibility" rather loosely. :)

Comment: I know it's my responsibility, I should have taken care of it earlier.  That doesn't help me now though, I'm in a sticky situation, and I was hoping maybe somebody could help me out.

Comment: @Adan Spend the five hours trying to solve the problem instead of refreshing this page. I'm not kidding.

Comment: I've been attempting for about 2-3 hours already on that 1 problem, I still have a decent amount of ground to cover on other parts of this project/homework.  I feel like this should be so damn easy, and there's something stupid I'm missing, that's what I'm hoping somebody can help me with.  If I didn't have anything else to do on this homework anymore, I probably would spend the rest of my time on it, but I don't have enough time to do that unfortunately :(.  


Ugh, I hate myself right now for doing this to myself.

Comment: @Adan So, the 5 hours are up. How did it go?

Comment: Eh, I figured it out with some help from my friend who happened to be up early.  I needed to set word1 to x ^ y ^ z and word2 to ((x & y) | (x & z) | (y & z)) <<1, so then when you add word1 to word2, it gives me x + y + z.  If I hadn't been up so late and tired, I probably would have been able to figure that out since that was fairly simple.  I was just freaking out a little bit I guess.  Thanks for your time though guys.

Answer (score 3):

Just a hint: `a + b == (a ^ b) + ((a & b) << 1)`. Here `a & b` is the expression for carry.

As you can see, by this transformation you reduce an add on N bits to some logical operations and an add on N-1 bits. If the N is given, you could manually unroll the loop and the whole result will contain only XOR, AND and SHL(1).